# Indexing of TD/TR with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, indexing, beautifulsoup

HTML Snippet:

```
<tr>
   <td class="faux_th">Unfinished Carport</td>
   <td>336</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
   <td class="faux_th">Finished Encl Porch</td>
   <td>96</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>58</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="faux_th">Finished Open Porch</td>
   <td>60</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
   <td class="faux_th">Base Area</td>
   <td>996</td>
   <td>996</td>
   <td>996</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="faux_th">Total</td>
   <td>1488</td> ##this is the value I need each time
   <td>996</td>
   <td>1139</td>
</tr>
```

Python with BS4:

```
houseArea = bs.find('table', {'id': 'ctl00_cphBody_repeaterBuilding_ctl00_gridBuildingArea'})
houseRows = houseArea.findAll('tr')[3]
houseArea1 = str(houseArea)
houseRows = houseRows.findAll('td')[1]
houseRows = str(houseRows)
houseRows = houseRows.replace('<td>', '')
houseRows = houseRows.replace('</td>', '')
```

This worked perfectly for the example I tried.  When I use the snippet above that contains 5 TR tags, obviously it breaks.  What I'm trying to accomplish is pull the second TD from the TR labeled "Total".  I've tried all sorts of ways, and I just can't come to some way of processing this.  Is there a way to index it from reverse?  If so, the position of the "Total" TR is always last.  My last option is to use regex to match the HTML, but even from there I'm not sure how to pull the results I need.  Any advice on how to tackle this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is, use `[-1]` as the index:

```
lastRow = houseRows[-1]
```

Negative indexes are subtracted from the current length of the list, so index `-2` is the one-but-last entry, etc.